# Chrome credential/smartlock pop-up: detect cancel/dismissed event (rather than no credentials)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-smartlockpasswords

in Chrome sometimes a user credentials pop-up appears (smart lock/credential management). When the smart lock pop-up appears a user can click "cancel" or the "X" to cancel this modal.

**Question :** how can I detect this cancel button click?

See the image

[image]

and this is close, but there is not distinction between no-credentials + user dismissed window (actively)

[image]

References: 
https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-credential-management/

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but could work

add var start = new Date(); before your logic

add this to your else logic

```
} else if (typeof cred === "undefined") {
    var end = new Date();
    // user clicked cancel becasue took longer than 100msecs
    if (+end >= (+start + 100)) {
```

We cannot distinguish between user-cancel || no credentials found

Assuming your PC is quite fast: if the if condition typeof cred === "undefined" is not called within 100 msecs then this must be a human mousing his way to the cancel button and clicking ... in between 800-2000 msecs ... for an average human